# Working with primary key field in legacy database using Django

Tags: mysql, django, database, legacy, inspectdb

I have to create a simple CRUD panel for an active MySQL database. When I try to migrate my application I receive the following error:

`AssertionError: A model can't have more than one Autofield`

I've read the following in The Django Book, Chapter 18:

> Each generated model has an attribute for every field, including id
>   primary key fields. However, recall that Django automatically adds an
>   id primary key field if a model doesn’t have a primary key. Thus,
>   you’ll want to remove any lines that look like this:
>
> `id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)` Not only are these lines
>   redundant, but also they can cause problems if your application will
>   be adding new records to these tables.

I have the same scenario with this field:

```
id_call = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

However, if I follow the above suggestion and remove this line, the original application (not the django application) using this table may not work properly because it could be calling data from this table using this `id_call` field.

How can I resolve this situation?

Comment: Have you read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/legacy-databases/#integrating-django-with-a-legacy-database)?

Comment: Yes I have. That's how I've proceeded so far. But this doesn't give a solution for my problem.

Comment: See this [Automatic primary key fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields). I am using `uuid=models.CharField(max_length=22,primary_key=True,blank=True,editable=False)` as primary key instead of id. There's no id field in my MySQL table.

Comment: show your models if you are not able to debug the problem.

Comment: Thank you sir. The `primary_key=True` was given already when I used `inspectdb` to create the model. However, when I deleted and typed it again, it started working.

Comment: @MiniGunnR So include your answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

For me, by changing `models.AutoField(unique=True)` to `models.AutoField(primary_key=True)`, while working with a Wordpress database.

I had about 4 of them in generated `models.py` by `python manage.py --database='olddb' inspectdb > models.py`. Here i used one more db, say `olddb`, if you use default db then you can remove `--database='olddb'`.

I tried running `python manage.py runserver`. So i fixed each line by things mentioned above.

Reference:-

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/multi-db/#